# Make report from CakePHP to Word document

Tags: cakephp, ms-word

Is anyone here who is worked with cakePHP and word docs?
I have to create one microsoft word file (.doc) from my application and generated text like some report:
example: when i click on some button i get some information in word file (show in new tab or downloaded file).

is there any cakephp plugin for that or something else?
i was gogole it, but unfortunately not welll results for me .

Comment: you can use this  https://phpword.codeplex.com/  It's a generic PHP library and not a cake plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, but the Word documents needed design and almost all elements that Word can do, so create an HTML and display as a DOC (easy but ugly) or use a library (more complex and difficult)...

My solution was to create a Word template, and replace predefined strings by code(tokens), with php you can use the functions from ZIP, because de docx is a ZIP itself, with php code I opened the structure of (docx) reading the XML's and replacing the strings, then rezipped.

Maybe I will post a class... this is my code in resume, first copy the template to a user_folder, reed XML data and replace tokens, then delete the items of copied word, and finally insert the strings as XML (with the data) and files.

```
    //Abrimos el archivo para leer los encabezados XML del documento de word.
    //Es importante que los documentos sean docx, nativos.  
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $res = $zip->open($plantilla);
                ///Errors       
                /*
                ZIPARCHIVE::ER_EXISTS - 10
                ZIPARCHIVE::ER_INCONS - 21
                ZIPARCHIVE::ER_INVAL - 18
                ZIPARCHIVE::ER_MEMORY - 14
                ZIPARCHIVE::ER_NOENT - 9
                ZIPARCHIVE::ER_NOZIP - 19
                ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OPEN - 11
                ZIPARCHIVE::ER_READ - 5
                ZIPARCHIVE::ER_SEEK - 4
                */
    //Si se encontro y pudo leerse, extraemos el encabezado, cuerpo y pie originales (archivos XML) de la plantilla de Word 
    if ($res === TRUE) 
    {
        $contenido=$zip->getFromName('word/document.xml');

        $pie=$zip->getFromName('word/footer2.xml');
        if($pie==false)
        {
            $pie=$zip->getFromName('word/footer1.xml');
            $unoPie=true;
        }
        else
        $unoPie=false;

        $encabezado=$zip->getFromName('word/header2.xml');
        if($encabezado==false)
        {
            $encabezado=$zip->getFromName('word/header1.xml');
            $unoHead=true;
        }
        else
            $unoHead=false;


        //Verificamos la existencia de la carpeta, esta es creada la primera vez al capturar los datos complementarios
        // del usuario, controller->Userdatas/add, sino estuviera creada la creamos
         $this->check_folder($id_usuario);

        //Copiamos la plantilla original a la carpeta del usuario, para en ella realizar las 
        //operaciones de reemplazo y actualización
        if(copy($plantilla,$copia_plantilla))
        {
            //****REEMPLAZO DE TOKENS
            //Una vez efectuada la copia de plantillas realizamos los reemplazos de tokens              
            //El extra token era usado para indicar desde donde se obtenia la información que no existe
            //en la base de datos como los recibos de pago, con cantidades que en su momento son pasados
            // y reemplazados mediante el uso del extratoken.
            $extraTokens=false;

            $contenido=$this->replazeTokens2($contenido,$id_object,$tipo_id,$extraTokens);
            if($contenido[0]=="false")
                throw new NotFoundException(__($contenido[1]));                             


            $pie=$this->replazeTokens2($pie,$id_object,$tipo_id,$extraTokens);
            if($pie[0]=="false")
                throw new NotFoundException(__($pie[1]));                               

            $encabezado=$this->replazeTokens2($encabezado,$id_object,$tipo_id,$extraTokens);
            if($encabezado[0]=="false")
                throw new NotFoundException(__($encabezado[1]));                                


                $zip2 = new ZipArchive();
                $res = $zip2->open($copia_plantilla);
                    if ($res === TRUE) 
                    {       
                        //echo "Se ha abierto correctamente la plantilla clonada para tokens";
                        //Borramos los encabezados, pie y documento para reemplazarlo con las cadenas ya con tokens                         
                        $zip2->deleteName('word/document.xml');

                        if($unoPie==true)   
                        $zip2->deleteName('word/footer1.xml');
                        else
                        $zip2->deleteName('word/footer2.xml');                      


                        if($unoHead==true)  
                        $zip2->deleteName('word/header1.xml');
                        else            
                        $zip2->deleteName('word/header2.xml');

                        //Sólo si la plantilla es Gafete, eliminamos la imagen barcode.png de la plantilla
                        //Hay que tener cuidado, de que si se agregan más imagenes, no cambie el número de la imagen
                        if($id_plantilla==3) 
                            {
                                //Barcode
                                $zip2->deleteName('word/media/image2.png');
                                //FotoUser
                                $zip2->deleteName('word/media/image1.jpg');                                 
                            }



                        //Agregamos archivo ya con los reemplazos.
                        $zip2->addFromString('word/document.xml', $contenido[1]);   

                        if($unoPie==true)       
                        $zip2->addFromString('word/footer1.xml', $pie[1]);  
                        else
                        $zip2->addFromString('word/footer2.xml', $pie[1]);  

                        if($unoHead==true)
                        $zip2->addFromString('word/header1.xml', $encabezado[1]);   
                        else
                        $zip2->addFromString('word/header2.xml', $encabezado[1]);   




                        //Sólo si la plantilla es Gafete, eliminamos la imagen barcode.png de la plantilla
                        //Hay que tener cuidado, de que si se agregan más imagenes, no cambie el número de la imagen                                    
                        if($id_plantilla==3) 
                            {
                                if(file_exists($barcode_user))
                                {
                                    $resultado=$zip2->addFile($barcode_user, 'word/media/image2.png');
                                    if($resultado==false)
                                        die("No se pudo agregar el código de barras");                                      
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                echo "No existe el código de barras";
                                }

                                if(file_exists($foto_user))
                                {
                                    $resultado=$zip2->addFile($foto_user, 'word/media/image1.jpg');
                                    if($resultado==false)
                                        die("No se pudo agregar la fotografía del usuario");                                        
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                echo "No existe la fotografía del usuario";
                                }


                            }

                        $zip2->close();
                        //echo "Plantilla reemplazada";

                        $link=$download_document;
                        $this->set(compact('link'));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                         echo 'No se pudo abrir la copia de la plantilla mediante la function zip->open(), verifique que sea un documento XML de Word (.docx) en la carpeta del usuario'."<br>";
                         echo 'Verifique su existencia en:'.$copia_plantilla."<br>";
                         echo 'Código de error:'.$res."<br>";
                    }

        }
        else
        {
            echo "No se pudo realizar la copia de archivos plantilla original a la carpeta del usuario";
        }
    //Cerramos archivo
    $zip->close();
```